# Return all rows above last row until condition is met in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that oscillates between negative and positive values. What I'm looking to do is find the value of the last row, and return a `dataframe` of all rows above it until the sign changes form negative to positive or vice versa.

An example of problem would be something like this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-10,10,size=(100, 1)), columns=list('v'))
```

creating a dataframe that contains numbers from -10 to 10.

What I need to do is find the very last row of "V" and return all rows above it until it switches signs. Running this code gave me the following output :

```
93,  3
94,  2
95,  0
96, -1
97, -7
98, -2
```

What im trying to get as new dataframe containing rows 96 - 98, and everything above 95 is not needed or sliced off.

Since the sign changes so many times inside the dataframe, im having trouble singling out the last change before the end of the dataframe (row 95)

I've tried various types of slicing with `iloc` and `.tail()` but haven't had any success.

```
df[(df['v'].tail() < 0).idxmin(): ]
```

is as close as I've got, however it only returns previous 5 values and sometimes it can take up to 20 index's to change signs.

I've tried in various forms

`data[: (df['v'].iloc[-1] < 0)]`

but I just cant seem to get exactly what I'm after.

A big hangup is the data set is hundreds rows long, so there are too many zero's or sign changes to go about other methods that I can think of, when I need data only after the last sign change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: example dataframe is not being shown how I wrote it I need to edit it sorry

Comment: I think a clearer explanation is needed. Is the input a dataframe with idx? **provide code that can generate the input dataframe you have in mind.** It is enough to generate the columns minimally. If you are wondering about the guide for providing example inputs, please read the following notice:[mre]

Comment: Ive added an edit with an example please let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example Code**

If you generate a DataFrame randomly, you must provide a seed. I will generate a new DataFrame as an example because you did not provide a seed.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, -4, 0, 1, 2] , columns=list('v'))
```

df:

```
    v
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   -4
4   0
5   1
6   2
```

---

**Code**

```
s = df['v'].mask(df['v'].eq(0)).ffill()
grp = s.mul(s.shift()).le(0).cumsum()
out = df[grp.eq(grp.max())]
```

out:

```
    v
5   1
6   2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple yet not very efficient way to solve your problem:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-10,10,size=(100, 1)), columns=list('v'))

# Create variable to store the last value from the column "v"
last_value = df["v"].iloc[-1]

# The list below will store all the indexes of the rows where the column 'v'
# values have the same sign as the last value seen on the dataframe
indexes_to_include = []

# Iterate from the last to the first row in the dataframe.
# NOTE: idx represents each index, and row the values from that respective index.
for idx, row in df.iloc[::-1].iterrows():
    # If the last value and the current value are either greater than or equal to 0,
    # or both are smaller than 0, then append current row's index to the
    # list of indexes that we want to select from the original dataframe.
    if (row["v"] >= 0 and last_value >= 0) or (row["v"] < 0 and last_value < 0):
        indexes_to_include.append(idx)
    # When the above condition is not met, then we stop the iteration because it means
    # that we found the first value that has the inverse sign of the last value
    else:
        break

# Filter dataframe so that it only contains the indexes we appended previously to the
# `indexes_to_include` list.
df_filtered = df.loc[df.index.isin(indexes_to_include), :]
```

For a dataframe that looks like this:

|  | v |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 |
| 1 | -1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 5 | 6 |
| ... | ... |
| 95 | 4 |
| 96 | -10 |
| 97 | -2 |
| 98 | -2 |
| 99 | -1 |

Running the above script returns the following result:

|  | v |
| --- | --- |
| 96 | -10 |
| 97 | -2 |
| 98 | -2 |
| 99 | -1 |

### Notes

Iterating through each line of the dataframe until
a certain condition is met is not very efficient. If performance is an issue
that needs to be taken into consideration, I would recommend finding some
solution that uses vectorized operations instead of going through each line
until a certain condition stops being met.

Finally, the above solution assumes that the last value of the column "v"
from `df` can contain either negative or positive values and that your goal
is to filter the last values in the dataframe until there's a change in the
value sign with respect to the last row.

Comment: Thank you very much for the time you took to write this! I have marked Pandas Kim as correct as it is more efficient but reading this certainly gave me a better idea of how to solve this on my own. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

A simple and efficient method would be to make a boolean Series identifying the non-zero values and performing a reverse [`cummin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummin.html):

```
out = df[df.loc[::-1, 'v'].ne(0).cummin()[::-1]]
```

Output:

```
    v
96 -1
97 -7
98 -2
```

Intermediates:

```
    v  ne(0)  rev_cummin
93  3   True       False
94  2   True       False
95  0  False       False
96 -1   True        True
97 -7   True        True
98 -2   True        True
```

If you rather want to rely on the change of sign (0 or positive vs negative), use:

```
m = df['v'].ge(0)
out = df[m.eq(m.shift(-1).ffill())[::-1].cummin()[::-1]]
```

Intermediates:

```
    v      m  m.eq(m.shift(-1).ffill())  rev_cummin
93  3   True                       True       False
94  2   True                       True       False
95  0   True                      False       False
96 -1  False                       True        True
97 -7  False                       True        True
98 -2  False                       True        True
```